# sorting on aggregate of value in a given field in elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have the following field in my index

```
field1:{key:value}
```

Is it possible to sort my query on sum of values in field1.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do this, assuming you know the fields ahead of time. It should be possible with some minor refinements if you need to wildcard the fields. This assumes the sibling fields on the nested type are numeric.

Example mapping:

```
  "test": {
    "mappings": {
      "type1": {
        "properties": {
          "field1": {
            "properties": {
              "key1": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "key2": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Default results:

```
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "type1",
        "_id": "AV8O7956gIcGI2d5A_5g",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "field1": {
            "key1": 11,
            "key2": 17
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "type1",
        "_id": "AV8O78FqgIcGI2d5A_5f",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "field1": {
            "key1": 5,
            "key2": 6
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Query with script:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "return (doc['field1.key1'].value + doc['field1.key2'].value) * -1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Logic taking the lowest score as the best score (least negative in this case):

```
{
  "took": 18,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": -11,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "type1",
        "_id": "AV8O78FqgIcGI2d5A_5f",
        "_score": -11,
        "_source": {
          "field1": {
            "key1": 5,
            "key2": 6
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "type1",
        "_id": "AV8O7956gIcGI2d5A_5g",
        "_score": -28,
        "_source": {
          "field1": {
            "key1": 11,
            "key2": 17
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hopefully this gives you the gist of whatever specific scoring logic you need